# Data not saved into database yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I am trying to insert some data into one of my tables. But I am unable to save it.

```
public static function setupEmail($ref_no,$customer_id,$install_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT es.`id` AS 'setup_id',es.`user_id` AS 'user_id',u.`email` AS 'email', es.`circle_code` AS 'circle_code',
es.`circle_name` AS 'circle_name',es.`email_group` AS 'email_group',ins.`meter_msn` AS 'msn', ins.`istallation_status` AS 'install_stat'
,ins.`comm_status` AS 'comm_stat'
FROM `email_setup` es
INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON es.`circle_code` = sd.`circle_code`
INNER JOIN `survey` sur ON sd.`sub_div_code` = sur.`sub_division`
INNER JOIN `user` u ON es.`user_id` = u.`id` 
INNER JOIN `installations` ins ON sur.`customer_id` = ins.`customer_id`
WHERE sur.`customer_id` = '$customer_id'";

    $result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();

    foreach ($result as $result_set)
    {
       $email_setup_id = $result_set['setup_id'];
       $msn = $result_set['msn'];
       $email_to = $result_set['email'];
       $install_status = $result_set['install_stat'];
       $communication_stat = $result_set['comm_stat'];

       $m = new EmailTransaction;
       $m -> load(Yii::$app->request->post());
       $m->email_setup_id = $email_setup_id;
       $m->install_id = $install_id;
       $m->ref_no = $ref_no;
       $m->meter_msn = $msn;
       $m->email_to = $email_to;
       $m->email_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        try{
            if($m->save())
            {
                Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setFrom(['xxx@xx.com'=>'Inventory Admin'])
                    ->setTo($email_to)
                    ->setSubject('New Installation')
                    ->setTextBody('The Meter# '.$msn.' against Reference# '.$ref_no.' is '.$communication_stat.' and '.$install_status)
                    ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
                    ->send();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            return ['status' => 'ERROR', 'message' => $ex->getMessage()];
        }

    }


}
```

I have tried to debug it and it doesn't get into the `$m->save()` part. I have also tried to do like `$m->save(false)` but it didn't help me out.

I am unable to send data and email. Below is the model code

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['email_setup_id', 'install_id'], 'integer'],
        [['email_datetime'], 'safe'],
        [['meter_msn','email_to'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
        [['ref_no'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['install_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Installations::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['install_id' => 'id']],
        [['meter_msn'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Meters::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['meter_msn' => 'meter_msn']],
        [['ref_no'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => RefNumbers::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['ref_no' => 'ref_no']],
    ];
}
```

**Update 1**

As a quick update, I tried both `print_r(Yii::$app->request->post())` and `print_r($m->getErrors())`. Both are giving me and empty array `Array()`

**Update 2**

My table definition is as follows

[image]

[image]

**Update 3**

After running this `SHOW CREATE TABLE email_transaction`. Below is what I get

[image]

The full text is

```
CREATE TABLE `email_transaction` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email_setup_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`install_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`meter_msn` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`ref_no` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`email_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`email_to` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `FK_REF_NO` (`ref_no`),
 KEY `FK_METER_MSN` (`meter_msn`),
 KEY `FK_INS_ID` (`install_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_INS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`install_id`) REFERENCES `installations` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_METER_MSN` FOREIGN KEY (`meter_msn`) REFERENCES `meters` (`meter_msn`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_REF_NO` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_no`) REFERENCES `ref_numbers` (`ref_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Update 3**

As per suggestion I have done the following

```
 try {
            if ($m->save(false)) {
                Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setFrom(['faisal.qayyum@accurate.com.pk' => 'Inventory Admin'])
                    ->setTo($email_to)
                    ->setSubject('New Installation')
                    ->setTextBody('Salam')
                    ->setHtmlBody('The Meter# ' . $msn . ' against Reference# ' . $ref_no . ' is ' . $communication_stat . ' and ' . $install_status)
                    ->send();
            } else {
                //throw new \Exception('error');;
                echo "No Email Sent";
            }
        }catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            print_r($m->attributes); return;
        }
```

The output is

```
Array
(
[id] => 
[email_setup_id] => 1
[install_id] => 1
[meter_msn] => 002999000071
[ref_no] => 20371110314300U
[email_datetime] => 2018-02-09 07:00:18
[email_to] => aaa.aa@aa.com
)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you are adding the record inside a `try-catch` block and without starting the `transaction` block although it would still work, plus the `$m->save()` wont throw and **Exception**  it returns `true` false and populates the errors to the attributes if you want to catch an exception you need to `throw` it too in the `else` section of  `if($m->save())`

Comment: and what is the point of `print_r(Yii::$app->request->post())` there isnt anything posted it will be empty ofcourse

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam ok after removing `try-catch` I have done this `$m->save(false)` and it gives me the following error  `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: you have  constraint added that isn't allowing you to add the record either because of a missing `primary key` or a `unique` key that is already added, can you show the table definition

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes kindly check the updated question

Comment: try running the following in your `console`  way and then paste in your Question, `SHOW CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam you are talking about browser console?

Comment: nope your sql console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164746/discussion-between-mr-faisal-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).

Comment: make sure you are supplying the all the 3 foreign keys from the dataset you have selected to insert thre must be one record that is missing one of these `install_id`,`meter_msn`,`ref_no`

Comment: what i have figured out is that you are allowing the foreign keys to have `NULL` then it should allow the `NULL` values to be entered but if the value other than `NULL` is provided and it is not available in the parent table then it would raise the foreign key constraint exception.

Comment: So should I checked them as `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Nopes, that wont get you to the actual problem that is raising the exception, you should revert the code back to its previous state as posted in the question and add `print_r($m->attributes); return;` in the `catch`  block and comment out the line `return ['status' => 'ERROR', 'message' => $ex->getMessage()];`  and show what it prints

Comment: and add `else{throw new \Exception('error');}` to the `if($m->save){`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam sorry for the late reply. I have updated the question as per your suggestion. Kindly check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I am able to solve my problem. The things I have done is below

The `foreign keys` that were assigned to my table column `email_transaction` were from different tables so first of all, I deleted all my `FK's` and then again added them again from the same table. Also, I have set all `FK` fields to `NOT NULL`.

[image]

At the server side, I have deleted the model and again regenerated it. Inserted all the records and they were successfully inserted.

```
 foreach ($result as $result_set) {
        $email_setup_id = $result_set['setup_id'];
        $msn = $result_set['msn'];
        $email_to = $result_set['email'];
        $install_status = $result_set['install_stat'];
        $communication_stat = $result_set['comm_stat'];

        $m = new EmailTransaction;
        $m->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
        $m->email_setup_id = $email_setup_id;
        $m->install_id = $install_id;
        $m->ref_no = $ref_no;
        $m->meter_msn = $msn;
        $m->email_to = $email_to;
        $m->email_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        try {
            if ($m->save()) {
                Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setFrom(['sender_email' => 'Inventory Admin'])
                    ->setTo($email_to)
                    ->setCc("cc_email")
                    ->setSubject('New Installation')
                    ->setTextBody('hi')
                    ->setHtmlBody('The Meter# <b> '  . $msn . '</b>'. ' against Reference# <b> ' . $ref_no . '</b>'.' is <b> ' . $communication_stat . '</b>'. ' and <b> ' . $install_status)
                    ->send();
                echo "email sent";
            } else {
                //throw new \Exception('error');;
                echo "No Email Sent";
            }
        }catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            print_r($m->attributes); return;
        }


    }
```

It does workes for me. Hope that it will help some one